# Getting jw player video source from url parameter using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jwplayer

I'm working on a site where I have many videos.

For using them I'm creating a separate page which I can embed on my site, but creating too many pages seems too much difficult. So I want such a page with jw player video the source of which I can define using url parameter such as **?url=** using javascript or jquery.

I mean that the final url I can use should look like the below one.
`https://example.com/pages/embed.html?url=https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4`

My code for the page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Site</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- JW Player -->
<script src='/jwplayer.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<div id="myVideo"></div>
<script>
// Setup the player
const player = jwplayer('myVideo').setup({
  file: '[video-source]',
  type: "mp4",
  mute: 'false',
  autostart: 'false',
  nextupoffset: '-10',
  repeat: 'false',
  playbackRateControls: 'false',
  controls: 'true',
  streching: 'uniform',
  preload: 'metadata',
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  abouttext: 'My Site',
  aboutlink: 'https://example.com/',
});
jwplayer().addButton(
   "https://freepikpsd.com/media/2019/11/download-icon-png-white-8-Transparent-Images.gif",
   "Download Video", 
   function() {
   window.location.href = 'https://example.com';
 },
"download"
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also one more thing if it could be done, can the url to file be base 64 encoded like the below one.
`https://example.com/pages/embed.html?url=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudzNzY2hvb2xzLmNvbS9odG1sL21vdl9iYmIubXA0`

If something's wrong feel free to correct me.

Comment: You want to catch URL parameter value   like: `https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4` or `aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudzNzY2hvb2xzLmNvbS9odG1sL21vdl9iYmIubXA0`

Comment: @shree if the second one can be done it will be great because it will make it hard for others to read the url to file and play the video as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your URL parameter value using `location.search` and `get('value')` method like below:

```
const qString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(qString);
const URL = urlParams.get('url');
console.log(URL); // For test
```

You can use base64 conversion of parameter URL before passing on URL. Javascript has built-in functions to do that.

```js
console.log(btoa("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4")); //Return aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudzNzY2hvb2xzLmNvbS9odG1sL21vdl9iYmIubXA0

//and to get orginal form :

console.log(atob("aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudzNzY2hvb2xzLmNvbS9odG1sL21vdl9iYmIubXA0"))
```

Example:

```js
//const qString = window.location.search; //  Get your URL.  I comment this line and give static value for test with base64 param

const urlparaam = btoa("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4");
const qString = "https://stackoverflow.com?url=" + urlparaam; // Create URL with query string.

//Get your URL
const getParam = new URLSearchParams(qString);
const dparam = (getParam.get('url'));

// Now create your  url for  player
const playerURL = "https://stackoverflow.com?url=" + atob("aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudzNzY2hvb2xzLmNvbS9odG1sL21vdl9iYmIubXA0")

console.log(playerURL); //  your url for player
```

Comment: can you please show a proper implementation of the code(a demo page).

Comment: Can you elaborate what you don't understand ?

Comment: I update the answer and give a full example. Let me know if you have any questions about the answer.